# Tolerance Fit with Spring Dowels

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners

I am designing a stainless metal base plate to mount an orientation critical sensor. The sensor has two 6H7 6mm deep holes to align it. One of the holes is a slot to allow for adjustment.

The sensor manufacturer prescribes a 6g6 pin (loose fit) but that would result in a nonstandard transition fit on the hole in my plate if I'm correct. Could I simply use a spring dowel instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard Ø8 m6 dowel pin in a Ø8 H7 hole in your plate, but have the protruding end machined to Ø6 g6. That gives you your standard hole in the plate, an interference fit for the pin so it won't come out, your g6 fit for the sensor and a step so its impossible to assemble the pin the wrong way round.

If you're worried about the pin passing through the plate, either put a counterbored hole in the plate with a step for the pin to sit on or make the pin from a drill blank or some other 'hard' steel with a Ø5 m6 section, the Ø6 end won't pass through the plate.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a slot and a round hole for alignment, how would you slide it for adjustment if one of the pins is a slip fit into a round hole. All you will be able to do is rotate it around that one pin! I would take the sensor to a machine shop and mill a parallel slot to the existing slot so that you can slide the sensor on two pins fixed in your baseplate. I assume there are holes for the screws to bolt onto the plate, if not, have the machine shop put them in also! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a channel external to the sensor if you can't (don't want to) machine an additional slot in the sensor. Just take some 1/8 or 1/4 bar stock and cut pieces to mount on your base plate so that the outside edges of your sensor just barely slide inside the 2 bars. Then you can use the existing hole/slot on the sensor as purely mounting holes for screws to secure the sensor inside the 2 "rails' formed by the bar stock pieces. This is all assuming that you only need to adjust the sensor location in one plane ( or two planes if need to adjust height off the stainless plate, just shim it up in that case).

Comment: It seems that you have two accounts. You can request that Stack Exchange merge them, if you want. The you can combine the two answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer William, the sensor must remain stock due to backup/swap speed. It is fixed on the plate with a circle of m6 bolts but locked in position by the two undersize dowels both 6g6 (5.996..5.988mm). What hole fit to use is my problem. Kind greetings, Wouter

Comment: Walter, not sure what you mean by "non standard transition fit to the hole in the plate". If you could be more specific I can help you, I used to design jigs and fixtures for all sorts of machines.

Comment: What I meant by nonstandard tolerance was that no fixed reamer is available probably, the hole is too much undersize. Im currently discussing with a lasercutter to directly cut to tolerance. But im still interested in simply using spring dowels.

Comment: You can try coiled dowel pins, it will be easier to mount and dismount the sensor from this this type of pin as opposed to a slotted dowel. I still like the idea of using the outside edges of the sensor itself for alignment like I mentioned in my second answer, then you won't have to mess with any pins and mismatched tolerances.